# Get List of MembershipUsers by ID?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membershipuser

I have a system that needs to show a business their list of their employees who can log into the system. So I need to get a List of MembershipUsers by ID. Is that possible? All I see is the GetAllUsers() method for Membership, but I really don't think that will work. There will be thousands of users, as each business will have their own list of employees, but I will only be needing a small segment of that each time (probably around 40 per business).  It seems an awful waste of processing to bring back thousands of rows just to query that for a particular subset again. However, looping through and getting each one individually is taking up to 8 seconds! My current code is below:

```
       foreach (int userAccountID in ListOfEmployeeIDs)
       {
            MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userAccountId);
            if (membershipUser != null)
            {
                dto.Username = membershipUser.UserName;
                dto.Email = membershipUser.Email;
                dto.Password = membershipUser.GetPassword();
            }

            //Include User's Roles
            dto.Roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(dto.Username);
       }
```

Is there ANYTHING that will allow me to get all the Users I need in one fell swoop (I need roles too)? Am I missing something obvious? It would seem like a logical method to include in the Membership class.

If there is absolutely no way to grab all the particular users I need at once, can anyone tell me some way to grab them quickly? Is my loop doing something wrong to make it take so long to get the Users?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like the .NET Role provider might be a better way to go if you're using one.

Comment: Aren't these users stored in a database table? Why don't you simply query the table directly?

Comment: @gregd can you please elaborate on the Role provider and what it can do to provide me with the list I need?

Comment: I agree with @Icarus, for querying purpose you will be in a better position to query using LINQ. There are so many extension method that will allow you to select as many or as less users you want based on your condition. You can use join to fetch roles as well in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, 
   out int totalRecords)

MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, 
   int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)

MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, 
   int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
```

Membership provider offers only 3 methods which return `MembershipUserCollection`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't have `FindUsersById`.

`GetUser` you are using is the only method that accepts GuidID.

```
MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
```

So you do not have other option, unless you create your own service class.